# php: count how long someone is one a website and insert number into database?

Tags: php, mysql

hi im not sure how possible this is, but is there a simple code which will start counting from the moment a user accesses my site, could i use the header tags to store a session with some php code to say when page is accessed set a time and store the time in my mysql table and count till the moment the user leaves the site/the session ends and calculate an end time from the amount of time counted?

I'm wanting to create a table called sessions in my db so i know how many people are on my site, i know theres google analytics but i would like to manage this in real time, so would appreciate any help or a point in the right direction thanks

```
// GET IP ADDRESS
 $sql = "INSERT INTO ptb_sessions (session_id, user_ip, session_start, session_end) VALUES (NULL, '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "', now() '....');";
                mysql_query($sql, $connection);
```

Comment: Certainly it is possible to measure times, either the session lifetime or the time span between first and last request to the pages. However that is only rough: unlike in rich clients there is no such thing like "closing" or "leaving" in a web application: the server never gets noticed that someone just closed the browser window or whether he is still reading or using the site. SO your measured values will very rough timespans only...

Answer (score 4):

From my experience the best method for keeping track of user is by combining ajax and php. You should send a notification from javascript in certain time gaps (lets say 60 sec) upon that, you can in php side update value for how long user is currently logged on your site.

Sample code:

**index.html**

```
<script type="application/x-javascript">
// js code in index.html

window.setInterval( function(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","background.php?ping=1",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}, 60000 );
</script>
```

**background.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
// ... your database initialization here, so $connection will be valid variable ...

// background.php
// ur initialisation
$session_id = session_id();
$sessionEnd = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$sql = "INSERT INTO ptb_sessions (session_id, user_ip, session_start, session_end) VALUES ('$session_id', '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "', now(), '$sessionEnd') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE session_end = '$sessionEnd'";
mysql_query($sql, $connection);

?>
```

Note: you need to use **session_start()** in background scription; sql on duplicate construction will automaticaly update your value - so there is no need to write checking for existance.

Comment: you should consider using a parepare statement method like http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 1):

Nope. PHP is server-side, so once the webserver sends the page out, that's that. You may be able to do it in javascript

One possible variant that can be done is to treat the last page view as the "end of session" - have a session time out after a set period (call it 20-30 minutes), and whatever time the last page was loaded is when the session ended. You can use a database to keep track of last loaded page time.

You can get the `Session_Id`, `Session_start`, `IP` easily, but not `Session_end`

Answer (score 0):

Even though PHP is a server side script, you might think about another approach and use php to analyze your webserver log to estimate the time a customer has visited your site. Keep in mind, that this cannot be perfectly accurate (as any JS solution e.g. Google Analytics would be, too). It is just an approximation based on path analysis.

```
176.28.xx.xx - - [28/Apr/2013:19:26:04 +0200] "GET /page1 HTTP/1.1" 200 5552 "-" "-"
176.28.xx.xx - - [28/Apr/2013:19:26:05 +0200] "GET /page2 HTTP/1.1" 200 5552 "-" "-"
176.28.xx.xx - - [28/Apr/2013:19:26:06 +0200] "GET /page3 HTTP/1.1" 200 5552 "-" "-"
176.28.xx.xx - - [28/Apr/2013:19:26:07 +0200] "GET /page4 HTTP/1.1" 200 5552 "-" "-"
176.28.xx.xx - - [28/Apr/2013:19:31:04 +0200] "GET /page4 HTTP/1.1" 200 5552 "-" "-"
176.28.xx.xx - - [28/Apr/2013:19:31:05 +0200] "GET /page1 HTTP/1.1" 200 5552 "-" "-"
```

In this case you would find out, that there is one customer (based on the assumption, that a customer is uniquely identified by his IP address) that has two intervals of (based on the assumption that we put up a threshold of 1 minute, where a new visit of the same customer begins)

- 3 seconds from 28/Apr/2013 19:26:04 - 19:26:07
- 1 second from 28/Apr/2013 19:31:04 - 19:31:05

A tool already doing that is [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net)

Further readings can be found if you are looking for

- data mining
- path analysis

**Bottom Line**: But this is just an approach to answer your question. I would use tools like [Piwik](http://piwik.org/), [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) or similar to track those. They are advanced and doing all the stuff for you, especially storing lots of plotting points, that are needed. Consider that such tracking tools increase the request rates to your webserver dramatically and since php needs to setup a database connection on each call, that tool you are seeking to build, will be quite expensive in server power.